# How can you delete specific element in a list in ReactNative(JS)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I making a todo list where whatever I type get's pushed to an array. When I mapped the array, I put a trashcan button where they can remove that "Todo" list. I tried `Splice` method but it did not work. For example, I have a list that says:

"Buy Milk"

"Get Eggs"

If I want to remove "Get Eggs", it is removing "Buy Milk"(It is removing whatever it is on the top). Can someone help how I can achieve this.
Here is my code(React native code):

```
removeList = (item) => {
  let val = this.state.noteList;
  let arr = val.splice(item, 1); // <= this is what I did but it is removing the first element of the list

  let complete = this.state.completedTask;
  complete.push(arr);
 this.setState({
 arr
})
};
```

Here is my Touchable Opacity:

```
<TouchableOpacity
  onPress={this.removeList}
  style={{
    height: deviceHeight / 10,
    width: deviceWidth / 6,
    backgroundColor: "#e6a25c",
    justifyContent: "center",
  }}
>
  <AntDesign
    name="checkcircleo"
    size={45}
    color="black"
    style={{ alignSelf: "center" }}
  />
</TouchableOpacity>;
```

This might seem a dumb question to you but I just can't seem to figure it out.

EDIT:
I tried to do a Flat list instead of mapping but it's not working of me. Am i doing something wrong:

```
let newNote = [] // This is new NOTE and NOT THE COMPLETED SCREEN

newNote.push(

  <FlatList 
    data={this.state.noteList} 
    
    ListHeaderComponent={this.renderHeader}
    
    renderItem={({item,index}) => {
        <View style={{height:100,width:200,backgroundColor: "black"}}>
     
      <View style={styles.newBoxView}>
        <Text>{item}</Text>
      </View>
      </View>
     
    }}
  />
  
)
```

Comment: What's the value of `item`?

Comment: You need a index, key or an id or the item itself to know witch one to delete. The splice start with the index, and 'qty' to remove in your case.

Comment: if you looked at the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) for `splice`, you would see that it returns the *removed* elements, and mutates the original array. Neither are what you want here. You need to return a new array with the item removed, without mutating the original.

Comment: Item contains nothing. The reason why I put item is for order for the splice to work if i just put splice(1) it is not working

Comment: @JB_DELR I am having a textinput where it is pushing to an array. So how would i have a "Key" or an id.

Comment: I think you are mapping the array to write your TouchableOpacity. So when you map, variables available in the callback are item and index, witch you have to pass as Key for each item, React need it. You can use the item index to delete this one

Comment: Can you show me an example?

Comment: you can find very good examples just googling "react todo app", but I recommend you to go through react docs first because you need to learn how the state works and how to manage data in a immutable way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer so if anyone have the same issue has me, Here is the code:

```
`deleteNote = (index) => {
console.log(index)
 let arr = this.state.noteList;
 delete arr[index]
 this.setState({
  activeCounter: Number(this.state.activeCounter - 1)
 })
}`
```

Here is my Mapping code:

```
  `this.state.noteList.map((item,index) => 
   <View style={styles.createBox}>  
   <View style={{flex:4,justifyContent: 'center',backgroundColor: 
   "lightpink",}}>
    <Text  style={{textAlign:'center',fontSize:deviceWidth/20,}}>
    {item.trim()}
  
  </Text>
</View>
<TouchableOpacity key={index} onPress={() => this.deleteNote(index)} style={{flex:1,justifyContent: 'center'}}>
<AntDesign  name="checkcircleo" style={{alignSelf:'center',backgroundColor: "#e6a25c"}} size={deviceWidth/5} color="black" />
</TouchableOpacity>
```

)`

I hope this helps. This literally took me 1 week to figure and finally I figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
removeList = (item) => {
  let val = this.state.noteList;
  let arr;

  for (let i = 0; i < val.length; i++) {
    if (val[i] === item) {
      arr = val.splice(i, 1);
    }
  }

  let complete = this.state.completedTask;
  complete.push(arr);
};
```

Comment: Thank you for answering my question but your code doesn't seem to work. In fact, its not even deleting!

Comment: I actually stated that `Item` has nothing in it. I just put it cause I wanted to try something but I failed.

Comment: when calling this function, give the item you want to delete as parameter, like removeList("Get Eggs")

Comment: I want to do this but how would I let the computer choose what i wrote for example:
1, Orange 2, Banana How would let the computer know that when I click banana to print out banana